# No need vertical scroll after using box-size:border-box

Tags: html, css

Cascading Style Sheet File

```
body{ background: #000; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; }
.box{ width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: #ff0000; margin:0; padding: 0; }
```

html file:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

I have used above code but why vertical scroll comes.

I don't need because I used `box-sizing:border-box;`

I need space around my box class without vertical scroll and height should be 100%;

Comment: Hi can you add also your html code, i think the problem it s because if you use height:100vh, you need to consider if you have some header you need to calculate the height: calc(100vh - #{$header-height});

Comment: So add this: height:calc(100vh - 40px);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have added padding to body as `20px` which for top and bottom
>   together is `40px`, so basically you need to decrease (margin or
>   padding) from it using `calc(100vh - 40px)` function.
>   **Example shown below**

**Note:** `calc` is not a cross browser solution, it will work on all modern browser [Read more here](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=calc)

```css
body{ background: #000; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; }
.box{ width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 40px); background: #ff0000; margin:0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `height: calc(100vh - 40px)`

```css
body{ background: #000; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; }
.box{ width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 40px); background: #ff0000; margin:0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

or add the `height:100vh` to the body, and the `height:100%` to the `.box`

```css
body{ background: #000; padding: 20px; height: 100vh; box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; }
.box{ width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #ff0000; margin:0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Scroll is not showing for ur code.. i checked in my browser.. which browser u r using and version of the browser plz?

Comment: but it is what you want, no? you ask how to rid out from the scroll..

Comment: Sorry. i could'nt understand ur ques? can u plz explain clearly?

Comment: hmm better you explain what you want to happen, since as I understand it you want the box to bee full screen with no scroll, but now you want the scroll back ..